# Why need UIlabel "behavior" checkbox in attributes inspector?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

There is a "Behavior" checkbox in attribute inspector of UILabel. Does anyone know what is it used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about this Behavior section?

[image]

If so I think you are misreading it. It is not that the checkbox is for behavior. It is that the group of checkboxes, enabled and highlighted, are in the Behavior section.

What these checkboxes do is set the options for if this UILabel is enabled and if it is highlighted. More information about what these properties of UILabel actually do can be found in the [UILabel docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Answer (score 0):

UILabel has enabled and highlighted states. This is simply turning them on and off.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html